# Difference between geodesics and principal lines of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

As much as I understand it, a geodesic line of curvature is a line on the surface such  that the projection on the tangent plane of its curvature vector is $0$ at every point. [Principal lines of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature#Line_of_curvature) are lines such that their tangent direction is coincident with one of the principal direction on the surface at every point.

> But I can't see the difference between them. Can anyone make it clear for me?

Comment: One obvious difference: through a given point there are geodesics going in any direction, not only in the principal directions.

Comment: wow, that was clear. Thanks a lot. Stupid me

Comment: @HansLundmark I guess it can be extrapolated that all principal curvature lines are geodesics; yet, not all geodesics are principal curvature lines?

Comment: @Antoni Parellada No, consider any curve on a sphere that is not a great circle. Since a sphere is umbilical, every tangent vector at any point is a principal direction, so every curve on a sphere is automatically a principal line of curvature. However, only a great circle is a geodesic.

Comment: @Ernie060 That is a perfect counterexample! Thank you!